# Java: Succinct way to import multiple constants

Tags: java, android

Is there a succinct way to import in Java which would be equivalent to the following statement:

```
import static android.view.View.GONE;
import static android.view.View.INVISIBLE; 
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;
```

I know about this:

```
import android.view.View.*;
```

But I would like to be able to control what I import, and not just import everything in the View namespace.

ANSWER: The answer is No.

Comment: Correction: that should be `import static android.view.View.*;`

Comment: You are using best way, then why are you looking for another one?

Comment: It seems like a bad way, because if the android.view.View were renamed to something else (hypothetically to android.view.View2), I would have to change 3 import statements whereas if I could do it in one statement I would only have to change one. Eclipse would help me change it easily, but it seems conceptually messy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no quicker way to only import *some* constants.  You can get them all, or you can list each one you want separately.

---

Actually there is technically a third option, not that it's necessarily better.  You do have the option to import *none* of them and use their fully qualified name each time you refer to them.

Comment: Thank you bemace, I didn't even realize that that was possible. Not that its very useful.